# fscanf не читает целые числа с потока

Tags: файлы, потоки-данных, c++

Программа элементарная, но я никак не могу понять. Нужно из текстовика вытащить целые числа, они разделены пробелами. Он мне заполняет массив одним числом -858993460. Если поменять массив на символьный и считывание посимвольно делать - все нормально, а числа он не видит. Объясните, пожалуйста, в чем беда.
p.s. подключен макрос безопасности в настройках компилятора `_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS`, без него на безопасность жалуется, сам компилятор собственно Visual studio 2012.
Текстовик содержит в себе:

```
1 0 3
0 0 0
2 0 5

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "iostream"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "conio.h"
 using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{ 
    FILE*fp;

    fp=fopen("C:\\1.txt","r+");
    int i=0,k=0,n=0,s[10];
    while(k<10)
    {
        n=fscanf(fp,"%d",&s[i]);
        cout<<s[i]<<" ";    
        i++;k++;
    }
    cout<<n<<"\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `"%d"` на `"%i "` или `"%u "` не пробовали менять (с пробелом)?

Comment: проверьте, правильно ли открылся файл. может, `fp == NULL`? выведите ещё и `n`. и ещё, попробуйте "r" вместо "r+".

Comment: А если десятое число добавить? Или читать девять чисел, как в файле?

Comment: что значит двух счётчиков цикла? по х и по у же нужно считывать, не?

Comment: нет, не нужно. Посмотрите внимательно.

Comment: @skained, для начала прочтите, что возвращает fprintf(). Это по поводу **последнего** числа (-1), которое Вы не увидели (вывод от `cout<<n<<"\\n").

Число -858993460 это 10-ый элемент в массиве s[]. Этот элемент не прочитан, т.к. **в файле 9(!!!)** чисел, а вы крутите цикл **10 раз**. На 10-м проходе fscanf() обнаруживает **конец файла** и в s[9] **ничего не заносит**.

Собственно, про это и все остальное Вам уже рассказали @KoVadim и @gecube.

--

Этот комментарий, как бы краткое подведение итога, объяснение наблюдаемой картины.

Answer (score 3):

А смешивать с и с++, да ещё в такой форме, как то не очень хорошо.

А ещё:

- conio.h
- отсутствие закрытия файла
- отсутствие элементарных проверок
- попытка прочитать 10 чисел вместо 9.
- использование двух счетчиков цикла:)

Странное число  -858993460 становиться понятнее, если записать его в хексе. Это просто 0xCCCCCCCC. То есть - неинициализированный массив. Отсюда вывод - fscanf ничего не читает. Это можно проверить, если выводить значение n в цикле - оно  будет равно 0 (fscanf возвращает кол-во элементов, которое смог вычитать).

Вывод - скорее всего не удалось открыть файл, проверьте это.

Comment: Согласен. Чуть опередили меня.

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, использование в С++

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
```

моветон.

Нужно:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
```

Во-вторых, если заголовочный файл стандартный - пишем угловые скобки, если он пользовательский и лежит в текущем каталоге - кавычки. В данном случае использование кавычек, ну, тоже не назвать хорошим тоном.

В третьих, `"conio.h"` здесь излишен. Из него ничего не берется.

В четвертых, никто не мешает создать файл в каталоге с исполняемым и путь вообще не прописывать. В таком варианте под линуксом у меня программа прекрасно работает и выводит все элементы, кроме последнего - он идет как `-1`

В пятых, желательно все-таки при выходе файл закрывать ф-цией `fclose`. Но это не столь критично - операционная система за нами подчистит.

Дальше уже просто лень писать.

Comment: этот -1 - это строка `cout<<n<<"\n";`. а -1 там, потому что fscanf возвратит его, если достиг конца файла.

Comment: значит промазал. Последний элемент - якобы 0.

> gaal@linux-lybs:~/test1> ./a.out                                                                                                                     
> 1 0 3 0 0 0 2 0 5 0 -1

Comment: вот. 0 - это просто значение 10 элемента массива. поставьте перед while что то в виде s[9] = 100; и посмотрите результат. а -1 я уже объяснил выше. Возвращаемся к [классике](http://hashcode.ru/questions/155912/c-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85?%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0=1&focusedAnswerId=170022#170022).

Comment: Да, да, согласен.